# MySql Update one table from another fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to update one table from another table and the query set all of the fields,customers.entry_company_tax_id,  to "NULL" which did not make sense to me.

here is the query, can someone tell me what I did wrong ?

```
UPDATE customers 
    SET customers.entry_company_tax_id = (
        SELECT prospects.account
        FROM prospects
        WHERE prospects.prospect  = customers.entry_company_tax_id 
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

They would be set to `NULL` if there are no matches.

I would start by using `JOIN` syntax for the update:

```
UPDATE customers c JOIN
       prospects p
       ON p.prospect = c.entry_company_tax_id
    SET c.entry_company_tax_id = p.account;
```

This has the advantage that it will only update matching records -- so no new `NULL` values (unless `p.account` is `NULL`).

Then, you can investigate if that is the right `JOIN` key for the two tables.  Are you use `entry_company_tax_id` is used both for the `JOIN` and for the field value?

Comment: The prospect database has some information, but not all. Prospects has the following fields "prospect" and "accounts". Company has "entry_company_tax_id" and I would like to update company.entry_company_tax_id with prospects.accounts when prospects.prospect = company.entry_company_tax_id. so will the query above work ?

Comment: @Sandwick . . . The link between the tables needs to be correct.  If you are getting all `NULL`s now, you are probably using the wrong columns.