# How to update one table from another with join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

There are a couple of questions asked at SO similar like this but I have followed them but no luck.

I am trying to update my wordpress `posts` table column from `postmeta` value.

`posts` table

```
| ID | ... |     order_date     |
|----|-----| ------------------ |
| 1  | ... | 2019-07-01 08:10:00|
```

I need to update this new `order_date` column from old `meta_value` data.

I have followed these questions and answers.

[mysql update column with value from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709043/mysql-update-column-with-value-from-another-table)

[MySql Update one table from another fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557591/mysql-update-one-table-from-another-fails)

```
UPDATE posts 
SET posts.order_date= ( SELECT meta_value FROM postmeta WHERE post_id = posts.ID AND meta_key = 'order_date' ) 
WHERE post_type = 'orders' 
LIMIT 1000
```

AND

```
UPDATE posts  
SET posts.order_date = (
    SELECT meta_value 
    FROM postmeta
    WHERE post_id = posts.ID 
      AND meta_key = '_order_date'
)
WHERE post_type = 'orders' AND order_date IS NULL
```

But no luck '0 Rows affected'.

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you

Comment: First of all, run your subquery separately and check whether it's returning some record or not. if it will return more than 1 record it won't update your data. possible error "error code 1242  subquery returns more than 1 row". It may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171474/solution-to-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-error

Comment: @Niklesh_Chauhan I have checked and it returns the correct result.

Comment: is `WHERE post_type = 'orders' AND order_date IS NULL` probably ambiguous? do you need to use `posts.post_type` instead?